# How can I set a temporary padding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

**Note:** I guess the title of my question is nothing to do with my real question *(kinda)*.

Here is my code:

```css
.one{
  background-color: gray;
}
.two{
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "one">
  <div class = "two">
    <span>something</span>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class = "one">
    <span>something</span>
</div>
```

I need to manage it how those two blocks look like the same. In reality, `div.two` isn't exist in the first of time and it will be added after a while. So I want to keep the UI without any change when `div.two` appends. How can I do that?

In conclusion, I need to have the same look for both `div.one` elements at the same time. Is that possible? *(noted that I want to both of them be like the first one)*

Comment: With a temporary class with the padding which you can later remove from the element once you append?

Comment: @yuriy636 Doing that by pure CSS isn't possible? Look, in reality, I've a plugin which highlights codes, I mean it sets some CSS properties to whatever which is wrapped into `<pre><code> ...`. Also it appends parent `div` for the content. like this `<pre><code><div class="parent>  ..."`. That `parent` class has a padding. and I want to keep my codes identical after/before highlighting.

Comment: Can't you just remove padding from div.two and add the padding to div.one?? They'll look the same then.

Comment: @Scott Actually doing that will solve the problem ... but `div.two` isn't in my access .. that comes from a plugin.

Comment: So, just set the css to `padding: 0;` for `.two.` Am I missing something?

Comment: @Scott No you are right .. I think `div.two{ padding: 0 !important; }` will solve the problem. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change where the padding is applied....

```
.one{
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
}
.two{
  padding: 0; /* setting this to 0 should override any previous padding declarations*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to use `visibility: hidden;` instead of appending a new one? Instead of appending just change to `visibility: visible;`

```
.one{
  background-color: gray;
}
.two{
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/bx2kwjmw/

Alternatively can you add padding to the parent element instead...

```
.one{
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
}
.two{

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/bx2kwjmw/1/

**Edit**, I was playing around with this some more and saw that the padding on parent div isn't a solution as once you insert text the height still increases because of that text size.

Here's a new fiddle showing how to put in invisible ghost text as a placeholder for sizing, then remove it when you append content with your plugin.

It's just one idea, should be lots of ways to go about it..

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/bx2kwjmw/5/

```js
$('.plugin-append-simulator').click(function() {
  var content = '<div class="two">something</div>';
  $('.one').html('').append(content);
});

// $('.one') | selects .one
// .html('') | removes ghost text
// .append(content) | appends your content
```

```css
.one {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0);
}
.two {
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1);
}


/* scaffolding. ignore this */.plugin-append-simulator { position: fixed;bottom: 0;left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);display: inline-flex;padding: 3px 8px 1px 8px;color: white;background-color: black;cursor: pointer;
}.plugin-append-simulator:hover { background-color: red; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">ghost text</div>

<!-- ignore, scaffolding -->
<div class="plugin-append-simulator">simulate plugin append</div>
```

older version that toggles padding from parent to child..

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/bx2kwjmw/6/

Comment: @Martin AJ I updated my answer as I saw that the padding on parent wasn't a good solution. The visibility hidden one is still okay if you're able to do it.